# Prevent Python packages from re-exporting imported names

Tags: python, module

In a Python package, I have the file structure

```
package/
    __init__.py
    import_me.py
```

The file `import_me.py` is thought to provide snippets of functionality:

```
import re
import sys

def hello():
    pass
```

so that `package.import_me.hello` can be imported dynamically via `import`. Unfortunately, this also allows to import `re` and `sys` as `package.import_me.re` and `package.import_me.sys`, respectively.

Is there a way to prevent the imported modules in `import_me.py` to be re-exported again? Preferably this should go beyond name mangling or underscore-prefixing imported modules, since in my case it might pose a security problem under certain instances.

Comment: If you are trying to import everything in a module into your current namespace, you can specify which names are exposed by default with the `__all__` attribute in the module being imported.

Comment: Yes, but in my use case (with `imp`, that is) `__all__` provides no safety. It only controls the `*` use case, but importing with `imp.load_module` circumvents it to my knowledge.

Comment: In that case, it seems like you should probably just be doing it a different way. `imp` does what it does, importing the entire namespace, and there isn't any way for those imports to be hidden. Your only remaining option would be to import `sys`, `re`, and so forth inside each function that actually uses them instead of at the module level.

Comment: What's wrong with the existence of the name `package.import_me.re`? If you don't want to use it, don't use it.

Comment: @msw I want to prevent it to be imported accidentally. The current implementation gets a request for the functionality `hello`, imports `package.import_me` and executes `hello()`, if found. If the functionality `re` would be requested for whatever reason, bad things™ would happen.

Comment: By the same argument, if you called `package.import_me.global_thermonuclear_war`, bad things would also happen, the mildest of which is that a NameError would be raised. The same answer applies: don't do that.

Comment: @msw ImportErrors are caught. And yes, in hindsight this might not be the best design. But the code is deployed and out there and I try to evaluate my options in how to fix that problem.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed/downvoted. It is very clear what is asked. A question should not be closed just because the programming language does not offer a good solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no easy way to forbid importing a global name from a module; Python simply is not built that way.

While you could possibly achieve the forbidding goal if you wrote your own `__import__` function and shadowed the built-in one, but I doubt the cost in time and testing would be worth it nor completely effective.

What you can do is import the dependent modules with a leading underscore, which is a standard Python idiom for communicating "*implementation detail, use at your own risk*":

```
import re as _re
import sys as _sys

def hello():
    pass
```

**Note**

While just deleting the imported modules as a way of not allowing them to be imported seems like it might work, it actually does not:

```
import re
import sys

def hello():
    sys
    print('hello')

del re
del sys
```

and then importing and using `hello`:

```
>>> import del_mod
>>> del_mod.hello()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "del_mod.py", line 5, in hello
    sys
NameError: global name 'sys' is not defined
```

Comment: Yes, I feared that would be the case, without putting out the rail gun (overloading `__import__`, sandboxes, ...). Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Is this how it works "in real life"? For example, when importing `pandas as pd`, I can't then do `pd.np`, even though Pandas clearly uses Numpy. *Correction* it turns out you *can* do `pd.np`. Woah. Never noticed that.

Comment: A variant of the underscore method that I have seen employed in some projects is moving the actual code to a submodule call `_internal` and then only importing the public parts of this module to the parent module. For example, move `mymodule.py` to `mymodule/_internal.py` and create a `mymodule/__init__.py` with `from _internal import PublicClass, public_func`, etc. (or `from _internal import *`, if `__all__` is defined properly). To me, this looks a bit cleaner than adding underscores to all imports.

Answer (score 11):

**Update.** *Some experience later, I'd strongly encourage the use of `__all__`, and discourage the initializer-function idea. There is a lot of tooling, that will be confused by it.*

## 1. Initializer function

An alternative might be wrapping definitions into an **initializer function**.

```
## --- exporttest.py ---
def _init():
    import os                       # effectively hidden

    global get_ext                  # effectively exports it
    def get_ext(filename):
        return _pointless_subfunc(filename)

                                      # underscore optional, but good 
    def _pointless_subfunc(filename): # for the sake of documentation
        return os.path.splitext(filename)[1]

    if __name__ == '__main__':      # for interactive debugging (or doctest)  
        globals().update(locals())  # we want all definitions accessible
        import doctest
        doctest.testmod()
        
_init()

print('is ``get_ext`` accessible?           ', 'get_ext' in globals())
print('is ``_pointless_subfunc`` accessible?', '_pointless_subfunc' in globals())
print('is ``os`` accessible?                ', 'os' in globals())
```

For comparison:

```
>>> python3 -m exporttest
is ``get_ext`` accessible?            True
is ``_pointless_subfunc`` accessible? True
is ``os`` accessible?                 True

>>> python3 -c "import exporttest"
is ``get_ext`` accessible?            True
is ``_pointless_subfunc`` accessible? False
is ``os`` accessible?                 False
```

### 1.1. Advantages

- Actual hiding of the imports.
- More convenient for interactive code-exploration, as
  `dir(exporttest)` is clutter-free.

### 1.2. Disadvantages

- Sadly, unlike the `import MODULE as _MODULE` pattern, it doesn't play
  nicely with pylint.

  ```
  C:  4, 4: Invalid constant name "get_ext" (invalid-name)
  W:  4, 4: Using global for 'get_ext' but no assignment is done (global-variable-not-assigned)
  W:  5, 4: Unused variable 'get_ext' (unused-variable)
  ```
- It also doesn't play nicely with IDE intellisense features.

## 2. Embrace `__all__`

Upon further reading, I've found that *the* pythonic way to do it is to rely on `__all__`. It controls not only what is exported on `from MODULE import *`, but also what shows up in `help(MODULE)`, and according to the "We are all adults here" mantra, it is the users own fault if he uses anything not *documented* as public.

### 2.1. Advantages

Tooling has best support for this approach (e.g. through editor support for autoimports through the *importmagic* library).

### 2.2. Disadvantages

Personally, I find that whole "we are all adults" mantra quite naive; When working under time pressure with no chance to fully understand a code-base before delivering a change, we can do with any help we can get to prevent "shot your own foot" scenarios. Plus, even many popular packages don't really follow best practices like providing useful interactive docstrings, or defining `__all__`. But it *is* the pythonic way.

Comment: you can get around the pylint problem by predeclaring your global variables

Comment: I have really put private initialization function into use for a while. Although it's fine for use alone, that doesn't play nicely with annotation however. Type checker like `mypy` and `pyright` tend to complain loudly when the type of global function / class is overwritten afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

There is no easy way to forbid importing a global name from a module; but in fact, you don't need to.
Python allows to use local imports instead of global:

```
def foo():
    import sys
    print(sys.copyright)

sys.copyright # Throws NameError
```

Neat and simple.

Actually, I think that using local imports should be a good practice and global ones are just a tribute to C or heritage from it.

**UPD**: Obvious downside of it is that `import sys` statement will be executed each time this function is called, which can be unaffordable.
But you can create a callable object instead:

```
class Callable(object):
    import sys as _sys
    def __call__(self):
        print(self._sys.copyright)

foo = Callable()
foo()
```

Though I personally don't like this approach it may work better with generic classes.

Comment: All the work of importing happens the first time it is done -- subsequent imports just create a local name entry, and so are nearly free.

Answer (score 3):

The solution might be to rethink your files structure and create a **submodule**.
Use a file such as `__init__.py`  to expose the variables that you want.

```
package/
    __init__.py
    import_me/
         __init__.py
         code.py
```

```py
'''
import_me/code.py
'''

# imports that you do not want to expose
import re
import sys


def hello():
    re.doSomething()
    sys.doSomething()
    print('hello')
```

```py
'''
import_me/__init__.py
'''

from code import hello
```

Comment: maybe you thought about this already but I am just leaving it here for other people that might not be very knowledgeable about submodules

Comment: if I want to import the package in another file *main.py* via `import import_me`, I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'hello' from 'code'`. To make it work I had to modify *import_me/__init__.py* to `from package.code import hello`. Maybe a python 2 vs 3 issue? (I'm using p3.7). Anyway, thx for this solution!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a 4-year-old question, but I found myself having to deal with this same problem recently and came up with a solution that seems to work.

This is the file structure we'll be using:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    import_me.py
    import_me_no_re_export.py
```

The contents of `package/import_me.py` (used only for comparison) are as per the question:

```py
import re
import sys

def hello():
    pass
```

Those of `package/import_me_no_re_export.py` are:

```py
def _():
    global hello

    import re
    import sys

    def hello():
        pass

_()
del _
```

The following `python` CLI session (Python 3.8.5) shows the results of this approach:

```
>>> import package.import_me
>>> import package.import_me_no_re_export
>>> dir(package.import_me)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'hello', 're', 'sys']
>>> dir(package.import_me_no_re_export)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'hello']
>>> set(dir(package.import_me)) - set(dir(package.import_me_no_re_export))
{'sys', 're'}
```

As you can see, the `import_me_no_re_export` module does not re-export the `sys` and `re` modules.

**Pros:**

- It seems to work like a charm, no side effects whatsoever.
- Both `mypy` and `flake8` seem to like this approach alright.

**Cons:**

- At least Visual Studio Code seems to not like it too much (IntelliSense will simply not work and only suggest the deleted `_` function for a module so altered).
- You need to sacrifice an indentation level.
- Boilerplate

As other answers pointed out, embracing `__all__` is probably the best bet, although it does not in fact address the issue; other than that, probably deal with the fact that these things are bound to happen.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of options:

1. Put `None` in `sys.modules` for the module:

   ```
   >>> import sys
   >>> import re
   >>> del re
   >>> sys.modules['re'] = None
   >>> import re
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     ImportError: No module named re
   ```
2. Use the [RestrictedPython package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RestrictedPython/) or the [pysandbox package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysandbox/).

Be sure to check out [this article on Sandboxed Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/SandboxedPython) as well.

Comment: Thanks! Sandboxed Python sounds interesting, but it might be problematic to put this on my system, which is already quite large (both in SLOCs and user base). The problem with the `del` approach is, that I can't use the module in `def hello()` then. I could import it inside the function, though, making my PEP8 linter cry in the process...

Comment: @Boldewyn yes, the first approach has many drawbacks, but all of the other approaches I know of bring much overhead. An idea I had but have not tested would be to somehow modify `__all__` to remove the modules you don't want imported, but I haven't thought through this / tested it.

Comment: Disregard, I just saw someone already mentioned this is in the comments, and your response is right on.

Comment: Putting `None` in `sys.modules` makes it so nobody can import `sys`.