# Can you hide imported modules from a sub package in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, python-packaging

My project is structured like that:

```
module/
  module.py
  /utils
    utils.py
```

In `utils.py` I import modules like `NumPy`, and when I import `utils` using `from utils import utils` (which I don't get why it wouldn't be just `import utils` and I'll be glad if someone could explain) I can access the `NumPy` module from `utils` with `utils.numpy`, is there a way to prevent exposing my imports from submodules/sub-packages?

Comment: These threads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302754/python-submodule-imports-using-init-py ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229580/python-importing-a-sub-package-or-sub-module for your sub-question.

This thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015605/prevent-python-packages-from-re-exporting-imported-names for your main question.

Comment: The last linked discussion doesn't mention [Python's new module-level `__getattr__` and `__dir__` functions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-module-attribute-access), and you have to dig for any mention of [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/simple_stmts.html#index-38).