# What is os.Mapping and why isn't it in the os documentation?

Tags: python

I am learning python and while using `dir()` to examine the `os` module I found an entry called `Mapping`.  I tried to examine it:

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> type(os.Mapping)
<class 'abc.ABCMeta'>
>>> help(os.Mapping)
Help on class Mapping in module collections.abc:

class Mapping(Collection)
 |  A Mapping is a generic container for associating key/value
 |  pairs.
```

I searched for "os.Mapping" on the python docs site but no luck:  https://docs.python.org/3/search.html?q=os.Mapping&check_keywords=yes&area=default

Why does the help say Mapping is in module collections but `dir(os)` shows it is in module `os`?

```
[... 'Mapping', ...]
```

I also looked on https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html but there is nothing called "Mapping" there.

Comment: _"Help on class Mapping in module collections.abc"_ -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping. You can see it imported at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2ade563abc95281be595b6dc58a519e84b74d6e0/Lib/os.py#L663-L664.

Comment: If something isn't in the documentation, don't touch it.

Comment: It's in `os` because `os` imports it from `abc` (but it's not meant to be part of the interface of `os` - see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015605/prevent-python-packages-from-re-exporting-imported-names).

Comment: @jonrsharpe That basically answers my question though I don't know what abstract base classes are or why os imports them, but that's okay, at least I know where the documentation for it is and why it shows up in the os namespace.  I would be happy to accept that as answer.  Thank you!

Comment: @user2357112 From earlier today: "[Reading the corresponding doc is optional](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/104719#issuecomment-1556202310)" :-)

Answer (score -1):

@jonrsharpe and @mkrieger1 basically answered this in the comments above -- Mapping is imported by os from abc, that's why it shows up in the os namespace.