# Preventing the modules, classes and functions to be propagated with the package

Tags: python, import, pip, package

I have the following code in my abc.py file (as an example):

```
import numpy as np

def func(a):
    return np.sum(a)
```

In my __init__.py file I have:

```
from .abc import func
```

I created a setup.py file where I only added name and version of the package. I run pip install -e .

Now, when I try to import from the package (in another location), the np (numpy) package is available. I tried to simply "del np", but the function outputs an error because it needs numpy to run.

How can I prevent this from happening? How can I expose just the func function in the package?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46858647/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+prevent+re-export